# What's the thread-persistence of Lua's Pluto library?

Tags: lua, persistence

In the [description](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PlutoLibrary) of Lua' Pluto library, it says it lib persist functions and threads.

```
Can persist any Lua function
Can persist threads
Works with any Lua chunkreader/chunkwriter
Support for "invariant" permanent objects, of all datatypes
```

Hmm, I can't imagine how the functions and threads to be persisted. Can I have some explanation about this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can persist any Lua function

This means that Pluto can persist any Lua function by persisting it's bytecode and all required upvalues. See [here](https://github.com/hoelzro/pluto/blob/master/pluto.c#L297) and [here](https://github.com/hoelzro/pluto/blob/master/pluto.c#L396) for source. When you unpersist it, you can call the function as usual. Note that it cannot persist C functions registered in Lua.

> Can persist threads

It persists the thread's stack and activation records, so when you unpersist it, you can resume where the stack was executing. Code is [here](https://github.com/hoelzro/pluto/blob/master/pluto.c#L506).

Answer (score 2):

The [source code](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/pluto/pluto/2.4) is relatively easy to follow and very commented.

What the lib does is determine what parts compose the functions and/or threads, and then store every part separately.

If you skip the code and just read the comments, here's how the two relevant functions look:

```
static void persistfunction(PersistInfo *pi)
{
  ...
  if(cl->c.isC) {
  /* It's a C function. For now, we aren't going to allow
   * persistence of C closures, even if the "C proto" is
   * already in the permanents table. */
    lua_pushstring(pi->L, "Attempt to persist a C function");
    lua_error(pi->L);
  } else { /* It's a Lua closure. */
    /* Persist prototype */
    ...
    /* Persist upvalue values (not the upvalue objects themselves) */
    ...
    /* Persist function environment */
    ...
  }
}

static void persistthread(PersistInfo *pi)
{
  ...
  /* Persist the stack */
  ... 
  /* Now, persist the CallInfo stack. */
  ...
  /* Serialize the state's other parameters, with the exception of upval stuff */
  ...
  /* Finally, record upvalues which need to be reopened */
  ...
}
```

So, as you can see, a function can be considered as a composition of a prototype, a group of upvalues and an environment (a table). A thread is two "stacks" (the call stack and the memory stack, I think), the state information (excluding upvalues), which is basically what variables had which values when the thread was defined, and the upvalues.

You may read more about upvalues in [PiL 27.3.3](http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html)